# How to animate arrayed objects with a delay?

Tags: animation

I have this spiral of spheres, created using the Array modifier and an Empty for the object offset.

[image: spiral]

I would like to animate the spheres, so that Sphere 1 moves, then Sphere 2 moves, then Sphere 3, and so on, like when an audience does "the wave." Each sphere will start moving when the previous sphere is about to stop.

Is there a way to add a time delay or an offset to animations?

Comment: i'm not an expert in this field, but that could propably be done in the animation nodes add-on with rather low effort

Comment: There is an add-on for this task,   are they one object or separate objects

Comment: @Chebhou They are a single object with an Array modifier.